# Symfony 2 functional testing

Tags: testing, symfony

I am currently trying to write functional tests in Symfony 2 for each of my routes. Right now I am testing to make sure all the elements of a form are present and that they are of the correct input type.  For instance:

```
// Make sure there is a description field
$this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('#form_description')->count() === 1);
$this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('#form_description')->first()->text() == 'textarea', "Unable to verify #form_description is <textarea>");
```

Unfortunately text() appears to return nothing and I'm not sure why.  Running phpunit with this test gives the following output:

> There was 1 failure:
>
> 1) fixnit\ReportBundle\Tests\Controller\ReportControllerTest::testNew
>   Unable to verify #form_description is 
>   Failed asserting that false is true.

How can I fix my test to get the name of the element returned by the crawler's filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/dom_crawler.html#usage) for crawler say:

> An instance of the Crawler represents a set (SplObjectStorage) of DOMElement objects, which are basically nodes that you can traverse easily

So, according to the docs, you should modifie your code to something like this:

```
$formCrawler = $crawler->filter('#form_description')->first();
foreach($formCrawler as $domElement) {
  $this->assertTrue(strtolower($domElement->nodeName) == 'textarea', "Unable to verify #form_description is <textarea>");
}
```